# Preserve action parameter on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two actions to create a Tag, an HttpGet and an HttpPost:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult New(String culture) {

  culture = culture ?? "en-US";
  TagNewModel model = new TagNewModel();

  ViewBag.Data = new { Culture = culture };

  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(false)]
public virtual ActionResult Create(MarkNewModel model, String culture) {
}
```

When I submit the form the "culture" in the HttpPost is null ... How can I preserve the culture value I set on the HttpGet?

Thank You,

Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to include the Culture value into the form with the name that matches the action parameter name. In your case "culture".

In the following example, I am not using any of the Html helpers. I'm just showing one way of doing it.

```
<form action="create" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="@(ViewBag.Data.Culture)" name="culture"
</form>
```